# Check if a variable has a specific string in it in an if statement

Tags: sh

I am trying to check to see if a string exists inside a variable inside an if statement.

```
if  [ -n $(echo "$RUN" | grep "Done running command.") ]; then
```

I know this can be done by creating another variable then checking if that is empty but I am trying to see if it can be done in a more streamlined way.

```
CHK=$(echo "$RUN" | grep "Done running command.")
if  [ -n "$CHK" ]; then
```

Any incite on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex matches, which will save the spawning of a `grep` command, for a better performance and bash integration:

```
if [[ "$RUN" =~ "Done running command." ]] ; then echo OK ; fi
```

(note that if the dot is withing the quotes, it acts as a normal dot, not a wildcard character: that's for the best for our example)

test:

```
RUN="ok, Done running command. Bye"
OK

RUN="not running command. Bye"
<nothing printed>
```